# Mysql query showing rows even I don't have any records

Tags: mysql, sql

I've 3 tables. blogposts, categories and blogpost_category_joins
I don't have any records in blogposts and in blogpost_category_joins.
I've only 5 records in categories table. 
And this query showing me 5 row with NULL values

```
SELECT post_id, 
       post_title, 
       post_text, 
       post_poster, 
       post_date, 
       post_slug 
FROM blogposts 
INNER JOIN blogposts_categories_join ON post_id = bcj_post_id 
INNER JOIN categories ON bcj_category_id = category_id
```

Why it makes this?

EDIT:

I've tried also (LEFT AND RIGHT) JOINS. I've tried all combinations

Comment: If you add the rest of the columns to the output, then you might get some insight into why the rows are being returned. Try "`SELECT blogposts.*, blogposts_categories_join.*, categories.* FROM...`

Comment: Do you mean that tables `blogposts` and `blogpost_category_joins` are empty? Then you must be querying another database that happens to have copies of those tables.

Comment: If you do not have any records in those 2 tables why are you joining to them? Maybe create some test records so it will be easier to check your query

Comment: Yes both of them are empty.
I'm not querying from another db.
@Bobby It won't be empty.

Comment: so if you do a select count(*) from each table, they each return 0 records?

Comment: @terpinmd, each returns 0

Comment: Of course, we don't know how you've verified all that information. But, to move forward, I suggest you edit the question and post a SQL dump that includes: 1) All trhee `CREATE TABLE` statements 2) Sample data for `categories`. Before posting, try it yourself in an empty database with a regular MySQL client (not a PHP program or anything that involves additional code). Most likely, the mere action of composing a test case will help you find the issue.

Comment: I've defragmented and flushed both tables and now output is 0 row.